# Azure Application Access Only Key Vault Keys

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

I have a multi-tenant application.
I need this application to:

1. Be able to read the keys in all vaults of all of the tenants (that grant consent).
2. Not be able to read any of the secrets.

I manage to get full access to the Vaults using delegated permission (user impersonation).
However that isn't what I want cause this permission provide me with access to the secrets as well.

I saw ( [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/rbac-guide?tabs=azure-cli) ) that there's a role for only accessing the keys.
The role name is: `Key Vault Crypto Officer` (`id: 14b46e9e-c2b7-41b4-b07b-48a6ebf60603`)

Question is:
Is it possible to make my application require (only?) this role. Which will allow it to read keys but not secrets? Not sure I'm thinking about roles the right way, I don't have a lot of experience with it.

Note that I don't mind asking for delegated / application permissions, if it matters.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note that, it's **not** possible to read keys in vaults of **all tenants** using multi-tenant application.

Assigning `Key Vault Crypto Officer` role to multi-tenant application under subscription gives access in reading only keys of **all key vaults** in only *one tenant* linked to that subscription, not other tenants.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I created one key vault named **`srikv07`** by selecting Azure role-based access control in **Access configuration** like below:

[image]

In the above keyvault, I created few keys and secrets like this:

**Keys:**
[image]

**Secrets:**
[image]

Now, I registered one **multi-tenant** Azure AD application named **`KVmultiapp`** like below:

[image]

Under my subscription, I assigned **`Key Vault Crypto Officer`** role to that **multi-tenant** application:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Subscriptions -> Select Subscription -> Access control(IAM) -> Add role assignment*

[image]

Now, I generated **access token** using client credentials flow via Postman like below:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id: <appID>
grant_type:client_credentials
scope: https://vault.azure.net/.default
client_secret: <secret>
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this token to read keys of `RBAC enabled` key vault, I got **error** like below:

```
GET https://<yourkvname>.vault.azure.net//keys?api-version=7.3
```

**Response:**

[image]

To resolve the error, you need to include **`tenantID`** while generating **access token** like below:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id: <appID>
grant_type:client_credentials
scope: https://vault.azure.net/.default
client_secret: <secret>
```

**Response:**

[image]

Now, I used this **token** to retrieve keys and got response successfully like below:

```
GET https://<yourkvname>.vault.azure.net//keys?api-version=7.3
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used the same token to get **secrets** of keyvault, I got `403 Forbidden` **error** as the role gives access to only keys.

```
GET https://<yourkvname>.vault.azure.net//secrets?api-version=7.3
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Sridevi for the detailed response. The only issue I have is with the "assigned Key Vault Crypto Officer role" step. I don't want my customers to do any manual work (such as assigning a role to my app). So is it possible to add something to my app manifest file? so that is requires this Crypto Officer role assignment or something like that? The goal is to avoid manual work/configuration on the tenants that use the multi-tenant app.

Comment: Not really. The preferred solution would be without any work on the customer side, not manual through azure UI and not through scripts. Just a single click on the consent page in order to grant the application it's required permission. Can't I use the application manifest in order to make the app require the "Key Vault Crypto Officer" role?

Comment: Assigning Azure RBAC roles by modifying the **app's manifest file** is not possible. You can do that only via Portal, CLI, PowerShell, or REST API. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-steps#step-5-assign-role). That consent page works only for Azure AD scopes like MS Graph, etc..., not for Azure resources that require RBAC roles.